# Nuxt mixin - Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, mixins

I'm creating a Nuxt application, where a specific menu should be hidden on mobile. So i've created a mixin plugin that has the property `isSmallScreen` which can be `false` or true.

**mixins.client.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import styles from '@/assets/styles/base/globals/_responsive.scss'

const debug = true

let breakpoint = parseInt(styles.breakpoint, 10)

Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      isSmallScreen: null
    }
 },
 created() {
    this.isSmallScreen = (window.innerWidth <= breakpoint)
  }
})
```

I've registered the mixins plugin in `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/base/global/mixins.client.js',
]
```

Now I expect `isSmallScreen` to be globally available. When I console.log `this.isSmallScreen` in the mounted hook in `layouts/default.vue`, it returns `true` for small screens, and `false` for bigger screens. That seems to work fine.

**The problem**

My default.vue layout template looks like

```html
<template>
<div>

  <client-only>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <f-nav-admin />
      <f-nav-top v-if="!isSmallScreen"/>
    </div>
  </client-only>

  <!-- page content -->
  <div class="page-content-container">
    <nuxt />
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

I expect the `f-nav-top` component do appear on large screens, and hide on small screens. Which also seems to work.

**But ..**

Even though the functionality does what it should I still get the warning as shown below.

`Property or method "isSmallScreen" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

I've been looking for a solution for a while now, but can't find the solution. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have just built your example and it works ("nuxt": "^2.12.1")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem. Inside the `<nuxt/>` component was a reference to `isSmallScreen` as well. On page reload, the property didn't exists on the data though. That's because I named my mixins file `mixins.client.js`

In the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) there is a part about **Name conventional plugin** which means that `file.client.js` will only run on the client, and `file.server.js` only SSR. So that's why the data from my mixin plugin was not available which resulted in the warning.

Changing my mixins filename to `mixins.js` did the fix for me.